# PHP Echo Without Spaces

Tags: php, echo

I want to do an echo without having a space, even if I define it with a space.

This is how I defined it:

```
$closed = 'not yet';
```

I want it so if I put this (with whatever removes the space):

```
<?php echo $closed ?>
```

it will display like "notyet" instead of "not yet"

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not use `str_replace`?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the space with [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
echo str_replace(' ', '', $closed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the .
for example:

```
$closed = 'not' . 'yet';
<?php echo $closed ?>
```

it will display as "not yet"